# With Asp.Net Cache, does an incomming queue of calls to an empty cache wait for the 1st call have updated the cache?

Tags: asp.net, caching

We are using Asp.Net Cache, by putting cache attribute on the WCF methods we want to cache, so we have no control of the caching code.

If one have an empty cache and gets 10 calls of the same kind, where the 1st call takes so long time that it does not have updated the cache before the 2nd call arrives, will the 2nd call try to do the same and so on until the 1st call has updated the cache?

We are experience this scenario with WCF using ASP.Net cache, and would like the 2nd call to wait until the 1st call have updated the cache. Is there a way?

Kind Regards

Comment: It rather depends on what your cache-accessing code looks like. You might want to think about how long a process should wait, and how they're supposed to know the cache is currently being updated, and other things like that.

Comment: Thanks. II have updated the question, it is Asp.Net Cache we are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lock statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to block concurrent execution of a piece of code by multiple threads like:

```
    static object lockKey = new object();
    ..
    if(isInCache)
    {
     return cachedValue;
    }
    else
    {
     lock(lockKey)
     {
      //Code that updates cache
     }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I have now updated the question and unfortunately we do not control the caching mechanism.